# Notepad++ -- Is there a setting to NOT display filename extensions in the Tab Bar?

Tags: notepad++

I'm using Notepad++ 8.4.1.  The Tab Bar displays the names of currently open files.  All my files have .txt as the file extension.  So for instance, I now have 2 files open: "Notes.txt" and "Links.txt".

Is there a setting to NOT display the names of the file extensions in the Tab Bar?  I.e., I only want to see "Notes" and "Links".

Thank you!

Comment: That was asked [as a feature request](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/12023/fr-file-tabs-names-icons-extensions-ect) (see the first item listed at the link) going on nearly 6 years ago (next month will be 6 years) that has not yet been implemented.

Comment: Ah! Thank You for answering.  I've spent hours looking for the solution (user manual, forums, search engines, etc.).  I was so sure there must be a way.  Good to know that I can stop looking.  It would be a good feature, though.  Thank you again.

Comment: I want his feature too. They say feature request should be asked at [repo issues](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/15741/faq-desk-feature-request-or-bug-report) and in fact there's [one asked recently](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues/12563).